# How to Use Do-while loop In Apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Currently my issue is that I want to Fetch Bank Detail Until Its Status Changes From null to Any value.

I am using Do while loop and **my issue are the iterations is running the only once**. Not able to find the exact reason for this.

Here is Code snippet

```
Bank_Statement__c bankDetail= new Bank_Statement__c ();

        do
        {
            i++;
            bankDetail = [SELECT Id ,Status__c
                         FROM Bank_Statement__c WHERE ID=:randomId LIMIT 1];
            System.Debug('bank '+bankDetail.Status__c);
            System.Debug(bankDetail);
        }
        while(bankDetail.Status__c!= null);
```

Comment: It might be more useful to understand the "why". You're just going to keep querying a record until it changes?

Comment: I believe this is an XY-Problem. Why are you trying to query a record over and over?  What does this data feed into?

Comment: Actually i am new to apex, so don't know about this. My requirement is to do apex pool in LWC. So please help me in this . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your do-while syntax. However, it looks like there's a problem with your logic and what you're trying to accomplish that goes against best practices. You shouldn't place SOQL queries into iterative loops. It's inefficient and puts you at risk of exceeding Salesforce governor limits. Second, your loop is *most likely* returning after one iteration because it's **finding a `Bank_Statement__c` record on its first pass that has a non-null status.** What do your debug statements output?

Why do you want to continuously query for this record until the status changes? What do you want to do once the status is set? If you're most interested in reacting to this field change, I would look into platform events, triggers, or process builder. Having a polling process within an Apex class is not the way to go about this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please tell me how to use apex poll in LWC. I am new to apex

Comment: @SahilMalhotra, there isn't any Apex polling that I'm aware of and it's unlikely anything like that exists since Salesforce is a multi-tenet environment (literally every org in the world is sharing servers with other orgs, so Salesforce needs to be conservative with computation time). Look into Platform Events, triggers, or process builder and see which one best fits your use case.